# invalid json after reading json, parsing to data, and json.dumps(data)

Tags: python, json

Considering the following code in python:

```py
    import requests
    import json
    url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/submission/search?ids=d1de8g'
    raw_data = requests.get(url)
    data = raw_data.json()['data'][0]
    js = json.dumps(data)
```

`js` does not return a valid json.
(this json can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Kerybas/a786d46e17e8351282e0eab9159c9860))

Any web parser will report a problem on the key `selftext`.
Elasticsearch will not accept this json.
That said, `json.loads(js)` works correctly and return the right object.

I suspect the problem is around json.dumps escaping the quotation, like in `C\'est`. But I am not sure how to handle that.
Ideally, I would like to limit as much as possible changes on `data`.

Comment: Looks like JSON spec doesn't deal well with unicode (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#character-encodings). You have an option of re-encoding your values somehow after the dump() is done or forcing ASCII with ensure_ascii=True

Comment: @MadWombat `ensure_ascii=True`  is already the default with python stdlib `json` module. It is already being used in the example above.

Comment: @nosklo maybe turning it off is the solution then :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I just added this at the end of your code:

```
with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(js)
```

I open that file and test it with online json lint, and it is completely valid.

Here's the full file contents:

```
{
    "contest_mode": false,
    "wls": 6,
    "send_replies": true,
    "updated_utc": 1568047643,
    "author_flair_type": "text",
    "domain": "self.france",
    "allow_live_comments": false,
    "subreddit": "france",
    "is_original_content": false,
    "whitelist_status": "all_ads",
    "author_fullname": "t2_7u9qc9o",
    "link_flair_background_color": "",
    "is_reddit_media_domain": false,
    "id": "d1de8g",
    "is_robot_indexable": true,
    "is_meta": false,
    "no_follow": true,
    "author": "Hideki__",
    "num_crossposts": 0,
    "num_comments": 18,
    "can_mod_post": false,
    "link_flair_richtext": [],
    "is_crosspostable": true,
    "pinned": false,
    "score": 13,
    "retrieved_on": 1567961258,
    "over_18": false,
    "pwls": 6,
    "all_awardings": [],
    "subreddit_id": "t5_2qhjz",
    "media_only": false,
    "thumbnail_height": 105,
    "steward_reports": [],
    "author_flair_richtext": [],
    "author_patreon_flair": false,
    "permalink": "/r/france/comments/d1de8g/champignons/",
    "gildings": {},
    "thumbnail_width": 140,
    "parent_whitelist_status": "all_ads",
    "is_self": true,
    "full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/france/comments/d1de8g/champignons/",
    "spoiler": false,
    "media_metadata": {
        "l8yvwzw2fel31": {
            "status": "valid",
            "m": "image/jpg",
            "s": {
                "y": 1500,
                "x": 2000,
                "u": "https://i.redd.it/l8yvwzw2fel31.jpg"
            },
            "e": "Image",
            "id": "l8yvwzw2fel31"
        },
        "g5ggrww2fel31": {
            "status": "valid",
            "m": "image/jpg",
            "s": {
                "y": 1500,
                "x": 2000,
                "u": "https://i.redd.it/g5ggrww2fel31.jpg"
            },
            "e": "Image",
            "id": "g5ggrww2fel31"
        },
        "vbk1czx2fel31": {
            "status": "valid",
            "m": "image/jpg",
            "s": {
                "y": 1500,
                "x": 2000,
                "u": "https://i.redd.it/vbk1czx2fel31.jpg"
            },
            "e": "Image",
            "id": "vbk1czx2fel31"
        },
        "blznmww2fel31": {
            "status": "valid",
            "m": "image/jpg",
            "s": {
                "y": 1500,
                "x": 2000,
                "u": "https://i.redd.it/blznmww2fel31.jpg"
            },
            "e": "Image",
            "id": "blznmww2fel31"
        }
    },
    "locked": false,
    "stickied": false,
    "total_awards_received": 0,
    "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/france/comments/d1de8g/champignons/",
    "link_flair_type": "text",
    "subreddit_subscribers": 293573,
    "created_utc": 1567961252,
    "thumbnail": "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/yS3060tLjUvrvHElg1nUCQwu7YPwKBdjNCXuhD4lqsM.jpg",
    "link_flair_text_color": "dark",
    "selftext": "Bonjour le sub, je suis enfin en vacances et dans le Livradois en Auvergne. Je cherche les champignons, je les fais s\u00e9cher et aussi du serpolet.\n\nJ'ai des girolles jaunes et grises, des c\u00e8pes, des pieds de moutons et je trouve un nouveau champignons qui je pense \u00eatre un polypore confluent. C'est l\u00e0 que je vous demande votre avis et tout ce que vous pourrez me dire de ce champignons tout nouveau pour moi.\n\nEt enfin la 4eme photos, c'est un champignons que j'ai pas du tout envie de manger mais j'aimerais bien conna\u00eetre son nom.\n\n[est-ce un polypore confluent?](https://i.redd.it/vbk1czx2fel31.jpg)\n\n[est-ce un polypore confluent?](https://i.redd.it/blznmww2fel31.jpg)\n\n[est-ce un polypore confluent?](https://i.redd.it/g5ggrww2fel31.jpg)\n\n&amp;#x200B;\n\n[Champignon inconnue](https://i.redd.it/l8yvwzw2fel31.jpg)",
    "title": "Champignons",
    "subreddit_type": "public",
    "is_video": false
}
```

I can see that your paste has double escapes, I'm not sure why. Maybe it's related to how you're printing the variable's contents.

Comment: Right, if I print(js) it looks like yours. In my gist I paste the output from a Jupyter Notebook. Then my problem is elsewhere...